# Create a XML object in Java

Tags: java, xml, sockets

I need create a xml object to send it by a socket, I can create a xml object like a json object?
I have this code to create a json object:

```
JsonObject o = new JsonObject();
o.addProperty("type", String.valueOf("message"));
o.addProperty("state", String.valueOf("complete"));
String send_message = gson.toJson(o);
communication.write(socket,send_message);
```

Where communication.write sends the string sen_message, I need to create an xml object like this to send it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not send a JSON object?    If you must have XML, look into the built in Document classes or try something like JDOM or DOM4J.  You should also be aware of JAXB, the object-to-XML binding API.

Comment: Because i need to send a Json object and xml object with the same information, but thanks, you have any example of xml object?

Comment: Is Google not installed on your machine?  http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/java-xml-parser-tutorial/

Comment: no i dont have google installed in my machine, but i have a web browser, thanks and I would like to know how to install google on my machine, tell me how??

Comment: You don't have much of a sense for sarcasm or humor, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Create the JSON you want to create and then call the following ....

```
StringBuilder xml = new ToXML().convertToXML(objJSON, true);
```

Download [Conversion Box](http://capsulesforthejavamind.blogspot.in/2015/01/conversion-box.html) for it ...

Answer (score 0):

There's a process called Marshalling and UnMarshalling in java.  It allows you to create an xml from a java object.  http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/30/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/